# WebSockets on DIY cartridge on OpenShift

Tags: websocket, glassfish, openshift, grizzly

I'm trying to build DIY application on OpenShift that implements WebSockets. I started with this example:

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api

If I run it locally, it works perfectly. When I upload the code to a DIY OpenShift cartridge and compile it, I get an error. I modified the code so that the Server connects to $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP on port 8000, but when the code reaches the line server.start(); it crashes with the following error.

What am I doing wrong? I tried other ports (17500 and on) without any luck.

Error:

```
Binding server to 127.7.177.1:8000
Jun 04, 2014 10:28:02 AM org.glassfish.tyrus.server.ServerContainerFactory create
INFO: Provider class loaded: org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.GrizzlyEngine
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:87)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:64)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractBindingHandler.bind(AbstractBindingHandler.java:140)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractBindingHandler.bind(AbstractBindingHandler.java:159)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:470)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener.start(NetworkListener.java:658)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:264)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.GrizzlyEngine$1.start(GrizzlyEngine.java:88)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusServerContainer.start(TyrusServerContainer.java:119)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server.start(Server.java:122)
at org.neo.wordgame.server.WebSocketServer.runServer(WebSocketServer.java:23)
at org.neo.wordgame.server.WebSocketServer.main(WebSocketServer.java:11)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Please press a key to stop the server.Jun 04, 2014 10:28:04 AM org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server stop
INFO: Websocket Server stopped.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application needs to listen on port 8080 on your $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP, but you need to connect to it from the outside at http://app-domain.rhcloud.com:8000 or http://app-domain.rhcloud.com:8443 (ssl).  Binding to port 8000 on your $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP won't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. I'm binding my server  to 127.7.177.1:8080, but I get the same error message.
This is the code:
import org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server;
Server server = new Server("IP",PORT,"/websockets",WordgameServerEndpoint.class);

It crashes when I run server.start();

Comment: Of course, parameter is IP, not "IP". That was just a typo, the code is correct.

Comment: make sure that you previously disabled the existing ruby server that binds to port 8080 in the default DIY application

Comment: The source code is removed, as is the entry in the start action hook. I checked with netstat and there is nothing bound to $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP.

Comment: Are you running this as a standalone JAR file, or are you running this inside of a servlet/application container like tomcat or jboss?

Comment: Well, locally I just run it as a normal Java application in eclipse and it works fine. On OpenShift I created a DIY cartridge and simply replaced the code with the one I used locally and configured the IP and port. I assumed that that the referenced libraries (javax.websocket-api, tyrus-server, tyrus-client, tyrus-container-grizzly) would take care of the runtime environment. Do I really need tomcat or jboss to run a websocket server application? Because this is exactly the scenario I would like to avoid and have a very simple java program that does this.

Comment: I just gave up and used WildFly8 as my container.

Answer (score 0):

It is just as [developercorey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2879327/developercorey) says. Latest news about WebSockets on OpenShift I could find is [this blog post](https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/), clearly saying that you have to access 8000/8443 from outside.

As a live example, I've deployed application using WebSockets into OpenShift. If you access it using http://vinbudin-openshift.anthavio.net/ui

Although application still works, because it can degrade to long-polling silently,
when you look into Chrome Developer Tool Network Tab, you can see rejected WebSocket upgrade request

```
Request URL:ws://vinbudin-openshift.anthavio.net/ui/PUSH/?v-uiId=0&v-csrfToken=bcd0c9a6-2a6f-4ddb-8332-7929e4337b2d&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.1.5.vaadin4-jquery&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json;%20charset=UTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true
Request Method:GET
Status Code:501 Not Implemented
```

But using url with port 8000 http://vinbudin-openshift.anthavio.net:8000/ui yields better result

```
Request URL:ws://vinbudin-openshift.anthavio.net:8000/ui/PUSH/?v-uiId=0&v-csrfToken=bcd0c9a6-2a6f-4ddb-8332-7929e4337b2d&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.1.5.vaadin4-jquery&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json;%20charset=UTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true
Request Method:GET
Status Code:101 Switching Protocols
```